# Laravel blogger

Tags: laravel, blogger

How to clone and use the laravel programs?
I did one but this shows this error

How to clear this error?

**ErrorException in Builder.php line 1015: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable', 'C:\wamp64\www\qwerrt\laravel-blogger\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php', 1015, array('scope' => array(object(Article), 'scopePublished'), 'parameters' => array(object(Builder)), 'query' => object(Builder)))
>
> at count(null) in Builder.php line 101
>
> at Builder->callScope(array(object(Article), 'scopePublished'),
>   array(object(Builder))) in Builder.php line 1315
>   at Builder->__call('published', array()) in Model.php line 1316
>   Blockquote
>   at Builder->callScope(array(object(Article), 'scopePublished'),
>   array(object(Builder))) in Builder.php line 1315
>
> at Builder->__call('published', array()) in Model.php line 1316
>
> at Model->__call('published', array()) in Model.php line 1328
>
> at Model::__callStatic('published', array()) in ArticleController.php
>   line 20
>
> at ArticleController->index()
>
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(ArticleController), 'index'),
>   array()) in Controller.php line 55
>
> at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in
>   ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route),
>   object(ArticleController), 'index') in Route.php line 203
>
> at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
>
> at Route->run() in Router.php line 559

I have this error , I tried something but I can't run this help me

What I do now...
This is the source code 
**ArticleController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Traits\RelatedArticles;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{

    use RelatedArticles;

    public function index()
    {
      $articles = Article::published()->paginate(config('blogger.articles_per_page'));

        return view('frontend.articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        $relatedArticles = ($this->getRelatedArticles($article)->count() > 3) ? $this->getRelatedArticles($article)->random(3) : $this->getRelatedArticles($article);

        return view('frontend.articles.show', compact('article', 'relatedArticles'));
    }

    public function favourites(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($request->input('id'));

        $user = Auth::user()->favourites()->toggle($article->id);

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

}
```

**Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Services\ParsedownService;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Article extends Model
{

    use Searchable;

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'articles_index';
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        if (config('blogger.search_engine.enabled') && !app()->runningUnitTests()) {
            static::created(function ($article) {
                if ($article->is_published === 1 && ($this->published_at < Carbon::now())) {
                    $article->searchable();
                } else {
                    $article->unsearchable();
                }
            });

            static::updated(function ($article) {
                if ($article->is_published === 1 && ($article->published_at < Carbon::now())) {
                    $article->searchable();
                } else {
                    $article->unsearchable();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        if ($this->is_published === 1 && $this->published_at < Carbon::now()) {
            return $this->toArray();
        }

        return [];
    }

    public function fans()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourites');
    }

    public function isFavourite()
    {
        return $this->fans()->get()->contains(Auth::user()->id);
    }

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    protected $append = ['author_name'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'articles_tags', 'article_id', 'tag_id');
    }

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('is_published', 1)->whereNotNull("published_at")->where('published_at', '<', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function updateTags($commaDelimittedTags)
    {
        $tags = explode(',', $commaDelimittedTags);
        $this->tags()->sync($tags);
    }

    public function setContentAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['content'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['html_content'] = ParsedownService::toHTML($value);
    }

    public function getAssociatedTagsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tags->map(function ($tag) {
            return $tag->id;
        })->implode(',');
    }

    public function getReadingTimeAttribute()
    {
        $words = str_word_count(strip_tags($this->attributes['content']));
        $min = ceil($words / 200);
        return $min . ' min read';
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'author_id');
    }

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:00');
    }

    public function getAuthorNameAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->author->display_name) ?? $this->author->email;
    }

    public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->category->name;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your laravel version and php version

Comment: My pho version is 7.2

Comment: Change it to 7.1 or 7.0 and check if the errors gone or not?

Comment: Hi, do you resolve the issue?